# Getting data from a sql table

Tags: sql

Hye there.. i got 3 tables looking like this:

```
create table Users
(
UserID int identity,
UserName varchar(50) not null,
UserAddress varchar(100) not null,
UserZipCode int not null, 
UserTown varchar(50) not null, 
UserPhone int not null,
Comments varchar(max),
primary key (UserID)
)

create table Groups
(
GroupID int identity,
GroupName varchar(50) not null,
GroupDiscription varchar(max),
primary key (GroupID)
)

create table UserGroups
(
UserID int not null,
GroupID int not null,
)
```

The last one is a table where all links between a user and a group is made.
i need to get the user data from all user that are in the selected group..

can anyon help me with this ?

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

```
SELECT Users.UserID,
       Users.UserName,
       Users.UserAddress,
       Users.UserZipCode,
       Users.UserTown,
       Users.UserPhone,
       Users.Comments
FROM Users
    INNER JOIN UserGroups ON Users.UserID = UserGroups.UserID
WHERE UserGroups.GroupID = @suppliedGroupID
```

Comment: Except of course you never ever want to use select *; get started correctly don't learn bad programming techinques. Only select the minimum fields you need.

Comment: @HLGEM Getting started properly would involve learning on his own rather than others just giving him the answers without any work or critical thinking. Telling someone something is bad and giving ZERO reason as to why isn't any better anyway. If you want to help him, explain why it's not a good practice rather than the "Of course you never want to do this".

Comment: @HLGEM: Agreed, just sloppy on my part.  It's good not only for selecting only the minimum but also helps prevent breaking things that rely on such queries if the table schema changes.  If somebody is, for example, referencing results in an array by index number.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a homework question therefore I will not give any direct answers unless you prove that you've put in the work and tried (I'd need to at least see the query you attempted to write).

I would suggest taking a look at using joins in SQL. Here's a good resource: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Ugh. W3schools should be linked to as a last resort. I consider them the Fox News of reference sites. Occasionally sorta right, always annoying.

Comment: W3Schools is fine especially for beginners.